# Android SDK Manager opens but will not let me click anything in System Settings-->Android SDK?

Tags: android, sdk, android-sdk-manager

[image]

It wont let me click on anything here. Not even the tabs (SDK Platforms/Tools/UpdateSites).

I was following the directions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) so that I could create constraint layouts.

I've attempted to move the original location of the SDK into the directory of where my projects have been created and that still hasn't worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue? I am running into the same problem. Very frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience your computer must have administrator privileges